# How do i make an action bar like this

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat, android-design-library

[image: actionBar example]

Hi, i´m making an app and i want to add an activity just like the image above, and i´m having difficulties extendin the action bar, i´ve seen this on google design guidelines, how do i implement this on android lollipop(my min sdk is 21 i´m not interested in backwards compatibility)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a `CollapsingToolbar` , you can use a simple `Toolbar` using a custom minHeight.

Inside the Toolbar you can put your views, for example `TextView` or `TextInputLayout`.

Finally use a `FloatingActionButton`. It is important to set the attributes
`app:layout_anchor`and `app:layout_anchorGravity`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarMainTheme" >


           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

           <TextView>


       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


     <!-- your scrollable view here -->        


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_card"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_youricon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_main"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by using `Collapsing Toolbars` which is provided in the android design support [library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and here is an [example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for knowing for using that library.

Comment: but I do not want to collapse , there is some way to achieve it?

Comment: @Ang If you wouldn't like a CollapsingToolbar, you can use a simple Toolbar.Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an EditText and several TextViews (or wrap the EditText in a TextInputLayout) into the Toolbar in your layout xml.

https://gist.github.com/chris95x8/53214de145571d410e13